# How to solve: "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to learn Selenium. I'm writing a script to add multiple items to a cart.

If I removed the class, the script allows me to add the item in the cart, however when I placed it under a Class, it's giving me this error:

```
C:\Users\bocse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\bocse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\EMAG\Sample2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bocse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\EMAG\Sample2.py", line 31, in <module>
    add_item("mouse logitech")
  File "C:\Users\bocse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\EMAG\Sample2.py", line 26, in __init__
    addcart = driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id=\"main-container\"]/section[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/button")
  File "C:\Users\bocse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 830, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\bocse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\bocse\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main-container"]/section[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.178)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x002737D3]
    (No symbol) [0x00208B81]
    (No symbol) [0x0010B36D]
    (No symbol) [0x0013D382]
    (No symbol) [0x0013D4BB]
    (No symbol) [0x00173302]
    (No symbol) [0x0015B464]
    (No symbol) [0x00171215]
    (No symbol) [0x0015B216]
    (No symbol) [0x00130D97]
    (No symbol) [0x0013253D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x004EABF2+2510930]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00518EC1+2700065]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0051C86C+2714828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00323480+645344]
    (No symbol) [0x00210FD2]
    (No symbol) [0x00216C68]
    (No symbol) [0x00216D4B]
    (No symbol) [0x00220D6B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75E900F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E37BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E37B8E+238]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

Here's my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
import time


class add_item:

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get("https://www.emag.ro/")

        # Search for item
        search = driver.find_element("id", "searchboxTrigger")
        search.send_keys(self.item)
        search.submit()
        time.sleep(3)

        # Select first item
        select = driver.find_element("xpath", "//*[@id='card_grid']/div[1]")
        select.click()
        time.sleep(3)

        # Add into the cart
        addcart = driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id='main-container']/section[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/button")
        addcart.click()
        time.sleep(3)


add_item("mouse logitech")
add_item("mouse razer")
```

If I removed the class, the script allows me to add the item in the cart, but when I make it a Class, I am encountering that error mentioned above. Any help please?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the issue is due to the Class creation. As per stated in the error, the Exception being thrown is  `NoSuchElementException` whereby the `WebElement` you trying to locate is nowhere to be found.

From my testing, it's working fine with your first query `mouse logitech`, however when it comes to your second query `mouse razer`. The XPath you defined to add to cart:

```
//*[@id='main-container']/section[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/button
```

is not entirely correct.

This is because on your second query, there's additional form exists in the web page, which recommending some product. Hence, the `XPath` you defined is no longer exclusive.

[image: Screenshot]

Hence, you need to define the XPath for add to cart button that are more exclusive and unique.

I have tried with :

```py
addcart = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='product-buy-area-wrapper']//button")
addcart = driver.find_element("xpath", "//form[@class='main-product-form']//button[@type='submit']")
```

they seems to work fine.